# Cannot delete batches of mail in Yahoo! (they just show as crossed out)

Tags: yahoo-mail

I am having a problem deleting mail in Yahoo! I clicked select all and delete, and it just crossed them out. Now, if I type `Twitter` into the search, I see all those emails, most of which I want to delete.

I also emptied the trash but this hasn't helped; all 126 emails show up there, no matter what I try. They're still showing all crossed out, rather than disappeared as I want.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or what, but I tested and it worked like this:

When an email is in trash, it appears as crossed in search results. When you empty the trash a deleted message shouldn't be in search results anymore but it still appears there. But if you try to search again (I mean if you search ***twice*** after emptying the trash) deleted emails won't appear in the results anymore.

Comment: I noticed my trash had 23 emails in it / 23 unread in it(I don't read email in my trash so 23 in it unread is 23 in it), and yahoo mail was still showing 126 crossed out.. I deleted my trash again, this time when it had the 23 emails in it. And then I think the 126  emails went.  Searching twice might've helped too. Also deleting trash twice and such that it didn't contain even a small number of email.